# Multi threading with each thread run sequentially to make multiple tiff image with unique file name

Tags: c#

I am currently working on project where the application take files from folder and reach each image for barcode. and when it reads the barcode it push all the non-barcode files in array and that array of files will be merged with multiple page single tiff Image with unique name in destination.
which all i done and its working but i want to make it fast using Threads.
i have function like -

1. read image files till it reach barcode.
2. make a unique name in destination folder
3. make multiple page single tiff image
4. save it in destination foler.

to read Barcode i use simple Barcode reader where i get Image have barcode or no.and rest i m doing with array in foreach loop. some code is here

```
 foreach (string path in filenames_1)

            {


                    Image bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(path);
                    Bitmap bn = (Bitmap)bmp;
                    readimage(bn);

                    if (s == 1) //If it is Bookmarked Content Found Then s=1 else its s=0
                    {
                        if (z == 0) // i used z coz in my process first file in directory is barcode image so first time have to skip it so i set z=1 at begining and second time it become 0 and process continues
                        {
                            j = 3; continue;
                            MakeUnique("c:\\sachin.tiff");
                            ConvertToMultiPageTiff(fileNames, fnamem);
                            fileNames.Clear();


                        }
                        fileNames.Add(path);
                        j = 1;
                        if (z == 0)
                        {
                            j = 3;

                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        if (j == 1) // j==1 means its regular tiff file wher i make them add to string array
                        {
                            fileNames.Add(path); // string array with files to be made multiple tiff image become single mulipage tiff image
                            j = 1;
                            z = 0;
                        }

                        if (j == 3)
                        {
                            z = 1;
                            j = 1;
                            fileNames.Add(path);
                            MakeUnique("c:\\sachin.tiff");
                            ConvertToMultiPageTiff(fileNames, fnamem); // this function converts all the added files in filearray of single tiff image to multiple page single tiff image
                            fileNames.Clear();


                        }

                        else
                        {

                        }


                    }
                }



        }

        MakeUnique("c:\\sachin.tiff");
        ConvertToMultiPageTiff(fileNames, fnamem);
        fileNames.Clear();
     }
```

Comment: Quite a big chance that this will be IO-constrained operation... as such "multi-threading" will actually slow things down as contention for HD increases. WTF are `s`, `j` and `z` and will you even be able to remember in a week's time?

Comment: If you're doing it "sequentially", there's no benefit to using multiple threads. The entire purpose of multiple threads is to do multiple things *at the same time*. "I wanna do it faster by using multiple threads, but I wanna run only one at a time" is nonsense; if you're running one thread at a time, there's no "faster" involved. It's still one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

try this logic

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading;
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{


    static class Program
    {
        private static ManualResetEvent wh;
        private static int total;
        private static int done;
        private static void Main()
        {

            string[] myfiles = new string[] {"file1", "file2"};
            wh = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            total = myfiles.Length;
            foreach (string myfile in myfiles)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessImageFile, myfile);
            }
            wh.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);

            //wohoo all files are process now, at faster rate;

        }

        private static void ProcessImageFile(object state)
        {
            string file = state as string;

            // process the file here

            Interlocked.Increment(ref done);

            if (done == total)
            {
                wh.Set();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Bro Thanks For the reply but as i debugged by using u r logic in processing of images like it takes one line for one file not complete code..

Comment: can u be a little more specific?

Comment: ok.. in u r logic the part of for each instruction of   " ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessImageFile, myfile); " in the method of  "  ProcessImageFile " if i start processing file like above it takes one line from that method and exit from the method and takes another file from that for each.. it wont finish complete process of that method. Hope u understood it..

Comment: but all the queue started runs parallel, try it w/o debugging, while debugging u wont really know if a app is multi threaded

Comment: i tried for that . but it gives error while reading image for barcode and says cant pass null values..

Comment: Waiting For Answers brother.